# AWS Lambda to Lambda invocation delays from time to time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The situation is like this.

1. Lambda 'A' invoke Lambda 'B' at 08:42:23.633
2. Lambda 'B' takes request from Lambda 'A' at 08.42:25.443 (almost 2,000ms later!)

Most of time, the time difference between 1 & 2 is less than 100ms. But sometimes it is almost 2,000ms like above example.

At first I suspected this as Lambda Cold Start issue, but it wasn't. This happens in the middle of serial Lambda invocations.

Any idea what other thing should I check other than Cold Start?

Thanks.

Comment: From where are you measuring those times? For example, how do you get the second time -- is it via a log message from the Lambda function? It is from the automatic 'START' line, or from a debug message in your own code?

Comment: Are other invocations of the same Lambda function running at the same time? If so, it is possible that the AWS Lambda service needs to provision another instance of the Lambda function to run in parallel. This requires the creation of a container. However, if it can re-use a previous container, it will be much faster. You might enjoy reading this series of articles: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)